# How to compare each row of a dataframe to the following 2 rows, and modify the current row based on these 3 rows and an algorithm? (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

How can I **compare each row's "Price" value with the next 2 rows**? I want to run a function for every row: If the current price is **lower** on any of the following 2 hours, I want to assign "**Low**" to the current row's "Action" column. If the current price is **higher** than on the following 2 hours, then assign "**High**". If the current price is nor the highest or the lowest of all the 3 hours compared, assign "Hold".

So how can I take the Price from each row and compare it to the following 2 rows with Pandas? The dataframe looks like this:

```
data.head()

    Date        Time    Price   Month   Hour    Action  
0   2018-01-01  0       2633    January 1       NaN 
1   2018-01-01  1       2643    January 2       NaN 
2   2018-01-01  2       2610    January 3       NaN 
3   2018-01-01  3       2470    January 4       NaN 
4   2018-01-01  4       2474    January 5       NaN
```

The desired output in this case would look like this:

```
data.head()

    Date        Time    Price   Month   Hour    Action  
0   2018-01-01  0       2633    January 1       Hold
1   2018-01-01  1       2643    January 2       High
2   2018-01-01  2       2610    January 3       High    
3   2018-01-01  3       2470    January 4       Low 
4   2018-01-01  4       2474    January 5       Hold
```

Thank you.

edit: probably can be easily done with for loops but I'm sure pandas has some better way to do this

Comment: Who ever downvoted this question, should at least comment with the reason.

Comment: What is the logic behind `Low` and `Hold` in row 3 and 4? Since there are no two rows to compare with? How does the last row know its `Hold`?

Comment: In reality to dataframe is much longer than 5 rows, I just compared those last rows to what is left in the .head() example (so "Hold" because there are no higher or lower values). But this algorithm is a simplification anyway, the real question is how one can compare each row with the next rows and then assign some values.

Comment: So I will post an answer which will only not take into account the last two rows of your dataframe. Since it has nothing to compare with. Is that sufficient enough for you?

Comment: I think that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `data['Price'].shift(-1)` to get the next price in the current row and `data['Price'].shift(-2)` to get the price 2 periods ahead in the current row. 
Next you can use slicing to select the rows where the next two rows are higher or lower than the current price and fill it with the desired value.

See below how this is done:

```
# Check if the current price is lower than the next 2 rows and assign to the column 'Action' the value 'Low' if this is true
data.loc[(data['Price'].shift(-2)> data['Price']) & (data['Price'].shift(-1) > data['Price']), 'Action'] = 'Low'

# Check if the current price is higher than the next 2 rows and assign to the column 'Action' the value 'High' if this is true
data.loc[(data['Price'].shift(-2)< data['Price']) & (data['Price'].shift(-1) < data['Price']), 'Action'] = 'High'

# fill the rest of the rows with the value Hold
data['Action'] = data['Action'].fillna('Hold')
```

Comment: What will this return for the last two rows? Did you check that? I think this will return `Hold` which is not correct.

Comment: It will return `Hold` like you specified.  In the question it was specified that `If the current price is nor the highest or the lowest of all the 3 hours compared, assign "Hold"`. Since there are no values it will be `Hold`. This will be overwritten when the next row is added to the DataFrame.

Answer (score 2):

We can write some conditions for this. And choose values based on those conditions with [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html). In our conditions we use [`.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) for this which compares the current row to the next two rows.

**Note** The last two rows will return `Unknown` since we don't have *two days* data to compare with. Which makes sense.

```
# Print the extended dataframe which is used
print(df)
         Date  Time  Price    Month  Hour  Action
0  2018-01-01     0   2633  January     1     NaN
1  2018-01-01     1   2643  January     2     NaN
2  2018-01-01     2   2610  January     3     NaN
3  2018-01-01     3   2470  January     4     NaN
4  2018-01-01     4   2474  January     5     NaN
5  2018-01-01     5   2475  January     6     NaN
6  2018-01-01     6   2471  January     7     NaN
```

**Define conditions, choices and apply `np.select`**

```
conditions = [
    (df['Price'] > df['Price'].shift(-1)) & (df['Price'] > df['Price'].shift(-2)),
    ((df['Price'].between(df['Price'].shift(-1), df['Price'].shift(-2))) | (df['Price'].between(df['Price'].shift(-2), df['Price'].shift(-1)))),
    (df['Price'] < df['Price'].shift(-1)) & (df['Price'] < df['Price'].shift(-2)),
]

choices = ['High', 'Hold', 'Low']

df['Action'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='Unknown')

print(df)
         Date  Time  Price    Month  Hour   Action
0  2018-01-01     0   2633  January     1     Hold
1  2018-01-01     1   2643  January     2     High
2  2018-01-01     2   2610  January     3     High
3  2018-01-01     3   2470  January     4      Low
4  2018-01-01     4   2474  January     5     Hold
5  2018-01-01     5   2475  January     6  Unknown
6  2018-01-01     6   2471  January     7  Unknown
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about .shift(), this is exactly what I needed. I'm trying to see for fun if pandas could be used for some price arbitrage optimization, next I'll refine the algorithm, conditions etc. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure no problem, glad I could help. If you need any more help,just ask :)

Answer (score 1):

I started from creation of the source DataFrame, a bit longer than
your *head*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[ '2018-01-01', 0, 2633, 'January', 1 ],
    [ '2018-01-01', 1, 2643, 'January', 2 ], [ '2018-01-01', 2, 2610, 'January', 3 ],
    [ '2018-01-01', 3, 2470, 'January', 4 ], [ '2018-01-01', 4, 2474, 'January', 5 ],
    [ '2018-01-01', 5, 2475, 'January', 6 ]],
    columns=['Date', 'Time', 'Price', 'Month', 'Hour']); df
```

The first step is to compute 2 auxiliary columns, `P1` with the price
from the next hour and `P2` with the price from 2 hours in advance:

```
df['P1'] = df.Price.diff(-1).fillna(0, downcast='infer')
df['P2'] = df.Price.diff(-2).fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

Then we need a function to be applied to each row:

```
def fn(row):
    if row.P1 < 0 and row.P2 < 0:
        return 'Low'
    elif row.P1 > 0 and row.P2 > 0:
        return 'High'
    else:
        return 'Hold'
```

And the last step is to compute the new column (applying the above function)
and delete the auxiliary columns:

```
df['Action'] = df.apply(fn, axis=1)
df.drop(['P1', 'P2'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```